# Confusion about Number.isNaN

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript with Eloquent Javascript.

In Chapter 2, there is a snippet of code:

```
let theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number"));
if (!Number.isNaN(theNumber)) {
  console.log("Your number is the square root of " +
              theNumber * theNumber);
}
```

I tried to understand the method Number.isNaN, and check on W3schools about it, and I get those examples:

```
Number.isNaN(123) //false
Number.isNaN(-1.23) //false
Number.isNaN(5-2) //false
Number.isNaN(0) //false
Number.isNaN('123') //false
Number.isNaN('Hello') //false
Number.isNaN('2005/12/12') //false
Number.isNaN('') //false
Number.isNaN(true) //false
Number.isNaN(undefined) //false
Number.isNaN('NaN') //false
Number.isNaN(NaN) //true
Number.isNaN(0 / 0) //true
```

What I don't understand about this example is that "Hello" is Not a Number, why it returns false.

So if Number.isNaN('Hello') returns false, applying 'Hello' to the above prompt, it will return true for this (!Number.isNaN(theNumber)), then it will execute this

```
console.log("Your number is the square root of " + theNumber * theNumber);
```

"Hello" * "Hello"??

I am very confused ...

Comment: Thank you :) , I think what I don't understand is ... isn't 'Hello' a string, and it is not a number, why it returns false for Number.isNaN?

Comment: Because that's not what `Number.isNaN()` is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `.isNaN()` functions: one in the global scope, and one a property of `Number`.  The global `isNaN()` first coerces its argument to a number and then checks to see if it is the `NaN` value. `Number.isNaN()`, however, performs *no* type coercion. Thus `'Hello'` is not `NaN` because, well, it isn't; it's the string `'Hello'`.  Only the actual number `NaN` will return true from `Number.isNaN()`.

Note that, confusingly, while `NaN` means "not a number", it does not mean it in the JavaScript data type sense. It's a part of the floating-point numeric system, meaning that the bit pattern does not conform to the standard rules for number representation. It does not give you an answer to the question, therefore, "anything that is not a number".

Answer (score 0):

isNaN only checks of is the value is NaN. If you try Number(+"Hello"), it will return true. So + sign here tries to convert "Hello" to number, but it fails and returns NAN.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is a special value of Number type. The version of Number.isNaN checks if the pass value is really 'NaN' (number type and is NaN), not anything Not A Number, the global 'isNaN' does that.

It's like `Number.isTwo(a)` (if it's exist), return 'true' if a is exactly two.

`Number.isNaN(a)` return true only if a is exactly `NaN`.

```
Number.isNaN(NaN) -> return true
Number.isNaN(!'Hello') -> return true because !'Hello' returns NaN
```

Look at the implementation of Number.isNaN bellow, it can explain well:

```
function isNaN(input) {
    return typeof input === 'number' && input !== input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "hello" will not pass the condition

<<< because a step back to :

```
let theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number"));
```

the author do a **coercion** using `Number()` which **guarantee** the  `let theNumber` will be either `a number` or `NaN`

after that in the condition:

```
if (!Number.isNaN(theNumber)) {
  console.log("Your number is the square root of " +
              theNumber * theNumber);
}
```

`Number.isNaN()` would be evaluate it correct and only numbers would be passes and `"hello"` will never pass because it coerced to be `NaN`